# Getting Error While Configuring Hbase In Standalone Mode

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Please help as i'm getting Error as **Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.local.etc.hadoop..lib while executing hbase**

But while running pig it's working.

Below are the conf paths of java and hbase

**#Java**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/etc/java
export JRE_HOME=/usr/local/etc/java/jre
#export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**#Hbase**

```
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/etc/hbase
export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_HOME/bin
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

**#pig**

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/etc/pig
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```